# connect to a database server without exposing a network share

Tags: database, database-connection, advantage-database-server

this is quite simple to do in many databases, but I have not yet found a way to achieve this with Advantage in Server-mode over the network.

assume 2 PCs:

- SERVER: running Advantage Database Server, and contains A database
- CLIENT: contains a simple application, or even just Advantage Architect.

If the folder containing this database was shared via the OS (network share, with read/write permissions), then establishing connection is straight-forward.

I am however, precisely trying to avoid exposing a network share.
In Firebird, for example, this can be done using connection path:
*SYSDBA@SERVER:C:\SomePrivateFolder\myapp.FDB*

Isn't this the reason for exposing a port for the database (6262)?

What's interesting is that they offer something called "internet" connection. I highly doubt they would require a network share over the internet to access the database.

So, is this doable, and if so, would love a hint.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

following the answer below, adding more details.

SERVER contains 2 folders, each one with its ADV Dictionary:

- C:\Data\mydata.add (*not a shared folder*)
- C:\DataShared\mydata.add (*shared folder*)

I am able to connect to the second one using the connect path \\SERVER:6262\DataShared\mydata.add

to connect to the first one i've tried:

- \\SERVER:6262\C:\Data\mydata.add
- \\SERVER:6262\Data\mydata.add
- \\SERVER:6262:C:\Data\mydata.add

none of which worked.

Note that I am not calling the stored procedure directly, but using the Delphi ADS components, which certainly internally call that same stored procedure.
I am certainly connecting as Remote (have the ADS Server launched on SERVER). For the other parameters, I am using TCP/IP as comm. type, and default ADSSYS / blank password.

with this setup in mind, what would the path be to connect to C:\Data\mydata.add on \\SERVER?

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to expose your database on a shared folder.  You'd only do that if using the LOCAL connection.  If using INTERNET or REMOTE, then simply connect using API AdsConnect60().   Look it up on the help file.

```
UNSIGNED32 AdsConnect60( UNSIGNED8 *pucConnectPath,
UNSIGNED16 usServerTypes,
UNSIGNED8 *pucUserName,
UNSIGNED8 *pucPassword,
UNSIGNED32 ulOptions,
ADSHANDLE *phConnect );
```

Furthermore, you can hide the path where your data resides by using a server side Alias.  Look it up on the help files.  It is quite simple.

To simplify things, do this:
Run ads server configuration utility, go to "Configuration Utility" tab and inside that, go to "File Locations" tab.  Write down path for Error and Assert Log Path.  Let's assume it is c:.  Let's also assume server is 192.168.1.1.

Now create a file named AdsServer.ini in that path (c:) with section: [ServerAliases] and a line adsdata=c:\data.   Now use API function AdsConnect60 like this:   AdsConnect60( "\\192.168.1.1\Adsdata\Mydata.add", ADS_REMOTE_SERVER, "adssys", "password", ADS_DEFAULT, &hConn ) ;

If you are working from Delphi or some other language make sure you check out the clases that are already built wrappers for the API.

It is all really-really well documented:  http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?ace_adsconnect60.htm

Comment: ... and don't confuse LOCAL, REMOTE, and INTERNET servers.  LOCAL is used when no ADS SERVER service is present.  It is useful on peer to peer smaller networks.   REMOTE and INTERNET require ADS service running on the target server.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply! Looking at the docs, I am not yet able to determine the path i must use: they give this as an example:  //theserver:31237/adsdata/testing, but this assumes "theserver" has a shared folder called "adsdata".

added an edit in the answer to give a well-defined folder structure and connect paths attempts.  Would you mind pointing out what the path should be in the newly added example?

Comment: amazing, thanks for the clarification! I mis-understood your original post, thinking that the server-side alias was optional to hide the data location. By setting it up as you described, things worked smoothly both by directly invoking AdsConnect60 and by using the Delphi ADS components.